# Shouldn't we Provide Explanations for "Unscientific" Questions?

Tags: discussion

I encountered **[this](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/12987/are-certain-craters-on-the-earths-moon-caused-by-a-plasma-discharge)** question on the main site that was deemed "unscientific" with no explanation, and then closed.

I believe that this site is for answering questions, not avoiding them. Shouldn't we be clearing up misconceptions for people, and not running away from them?

Comment: I completely agree.